# How to take input in a page using javascript and display the input in the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple web page, and I want to take input from the user and display the same in the web page, how should I write the Javascript code for the **output**? Currently it looks like this

```
var username = prompt("Your username")
var comment = prompt("Your comment")
println(username + comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document` API (this API represents any web page loaded in the browser and serves as an end point into the web page's content, which is the DOM tree) for that and fetch one of the elements in your html file. then you can assign its `innerText` to the answers you got.

For example (using the `getElementById`)

```js
var username = prompt("Your username");
var comment = prompt("Your comment");
document.getElementById("answer").innerText = username + ' ' + comment;
```

```html
<div id="answer">

</div>
```

More about the document interface [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for but you can edit the HTML value using :

```
document.getElementbyId('id').innerHTML = '';
```